# Getting #1064 error for below query?

Tags: mysql

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pset7`.`portfolio`(
`id` int(10)  unsigned NOT NULL,
`symbol` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
`shares` double(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 )ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

This is the error:

> ERROR :  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds >to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY >(`id`) )ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8' at line 1

I don't get what syntax error is, I checked on SQL corrector?

MySQL version - 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.13.10.2

Comment: Try removing brackets after `double`. `shares double not null,`

Answer (score 1):

`DOULE` needs two arguments

```
 `shares` DOUBLE(M,D) NOT NULL
```

D is the number of digits that may be after the decimal point and M is the total number of digits. For more info check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/floating-point-types.html) out.

Ofcourse you could also use this

```
`shares` DOUBLE NOT NULL
```

indicating to the sql engine to take the default values.

Answer (score 0):

`MySQL permits a nonstandard syntax:` `FLOAT(M,D) or REAL(M,D) or DOUBLE PRECISION(M,D)`. Here, “`(M,D)`” means than values can be stored with up to M digits in total, of which D digits may be after the decimal point. For example, a column defined as `FLOAT(7,4)` will look like `-999.9999` when displayed. `MySQL` performs rounding when storing values, so if you insert `999.00009` into a `FLOAT(7,4)` column, the approximate result is 999.0001

So try with

```
CREATE TABLE `portfolio` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `symbol` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shares` double(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/floating-point-types.html